# Why isn't std::vector::at a const function?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm trying to implement std::vector but I encountered the question.
According to C++ reference, `std::vector::at` is like:

```
      reference at (size_type n);
const_reference at (size_type n) const;
```

My question is: Why don't I use `reference at (size_type n) const;`?

Thank you for any help or criticism!

---

**Update:**
Thanks! I'm clear about that.

My fault is that I don't konw functions with and without `const` are also a kind of overload. The original design is to use the one with `const` when a const vector calls it, so it'll return a const_reference. When a vector which is not const, then the return value shouldn't be const_reference.

But if we make the 2 functions both `const`, then the 2 functions will have no differences except for the return type which is not a legal override. So the former one is not designed to be `const` though it can be `const`.

Thanks!

Comment: You can do that, no problem. It's against the C++ standard and may come unexpected to others though.

Comment: v.at(42) = 1234

Comment: The trailing `const` on a member function applies to the implicit `this` parameter.  So a member functions `void Foo::Reset();` and `void Foo::Dump() const;` are *sort of like* (pseudo-code) `void Foo::Reset(Foo* const this)` and `void Foo::Dump(Foo const* const this);`

Comment: @Eljay Thanks! This helps me a lot as I thought it was `Foo const *this` when I wrote that update; but it's in fact `Foo const * const this` as you pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the issue that a `ref at (size_type n) const;` could cause. First of all, you need to understand why `const_reference at (size_type n) const;` exists. In a `const std::vector`, once it is initialized, it or its elements are not supposed to be changed (because it is, after all, `const`). The normal `reference at (size_type n);` will *not* work for a `const` vector, because it returns a non-`const` reference to an element, meaning it can be changed. This goes against the idea of `const`ing your object, which is why this specific overload would not work for a `const` vector.

This is where `const_reference at (size_type n) const;` comes in. As you may know, the end `const` is a promise to the compiler and the programmer that this will not change its object or provide the opportunity for its object to be changed, so it can be used with a `const` object. In the case of `const_reference at (size_type n) const;`, this is indeed true: it returns a `const` reference, meaning the element you get cannot be changed. This guarantees that your `const` vector is indeed `const` and it will not be changed.

This is why `reference at (size_type n) const;` is a problem. You're lying to both the compiler and the programmer by saying that this is safe to use on a `const` object, where in fact it is indeed not, because since it returns a mutable reference, you can easily change the element you get with `at`.

Just ask yourself: wouldn't you be shocked if this program worked?

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    const std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
    a.at(0) = 10;
}
```

Comment: `reference at (size_type n) const` isn't such a big "problem" because it would not compile

Comment: Thanks! I'm clear about that. My original thought is to use both `reference at (size_type n) const;` and `creference at (size_type n) const;` but I didn't realize that this will not form a legal overload. Thanks again for your explanation!

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number maybe it depends on how the vector is implemented. In [this small test I did](https://godbolt.org/z/M74xTxaG9), it seems that the compiler is unable to catch the issue.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 oh, you are right. I was thinking of returning a non-const reference to member of const this, which would of course fail. The array element aren't const even on a const `foo` .